# c# - Linq select properties from List of objects and modify them with shorthand conditional

Tags: c#, linq

I am exploring doing some Array Binding with Oracle procedures, and need to split my List of objects into arrays of each of their properties.

I am doing so like this:

```
List<ReviewReasons> reasons; // actually comes from method call

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("checked_flag", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input))

cmd.Parameters["checked_flag"].Value = reasons.Select(x => x.CheckedFlag).ToArray();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The issue I am having is that the `reasons.CheckedFlag` value is a bool, but the database is expecting either a 0 or 1. Before I started playing around with the Array Binding, I handled the conversion within a `foreach` like so:

```
foreach(reason in reasons)
{
    string checkedFlag = reason.CheckedFlag ? "1" : "0";
    // then push into an array  
}
```

I was wondering if I can somehow us the `reason.CheckedFlag ? "1" : "0";` condition in the lambda of my Select. I am really new to Linq so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    cmd.Parameters["checked_flag"].Value 
= reasons.Select(x => x.CheckedFlag ? "1" : "0").ToArray();
```

Comment: This is correct, but I would also suggest that since you're going to run into this problem more than once, you might want to make a wrapper function for your evaluation that returns a boolean value. Bits like this go very well with some error handling that confirms the collection isn't null and similar.